# flutter CachedNetworkImageProvider is not working

Tags: dart, flutter-image

```
CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    backgroundImage: 
                        user.profileImageUrl.isEmpty 
                            ? AssetImage('assets/images/user.png') 
                            : CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.profileImageUrl),
                  ),
```

It says the 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.

and when I hit the flutter run, it is giving me the following

```
/C:/Users/Acer/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-1.1.3/lib/src/cached_network_image_provider.dart:42:24: Error: The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.  
  ImageStreamCompleter load(CachedNetworkImageProvider key) {
                       ^
/D:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
  ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using rc version of [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image/versions/2.0.0-rc).

Add this to your `pubspec.yaml` file `cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc` and run `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 1):

use this one on you pubspec.yamal
cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc.1
or use this one 
cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc
let me me know if it works.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I user ^2.0.0-rc and it is working. Thanks a lot

Comment: if you have got the desired output, then just make the upvote and mark it checked, so that it will be helpful for others.
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/renefloor/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/336 I'm having this issue after change 1.1.3 with 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode and you have added the `cached_network_image` recently to `pubspec.yaml` then try to **stop** your app and **run again** then it will start work

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today, the things I have follow:

1. try to delete .idea folder. (Not working for me).
2. Flutter clean. (Not working for me).
3. Remove `cached_network_image` from pubspec.yaml and pub get. again add and pub get. (Working perfect for me).

If its work for you then give this answer up vote. Thank you!